# Set dynamical max with field that have money-mask

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) and [angular input mask](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks) to create my fields.
So, I have two fields like this:

```
<form name="myForm" layout="row" >
 <md-content layout-padding layout="column" flex="40">
  <md-input-container md-no-float >
   <span>This is first field</span>
   <input name="field1" ng-model="field1"  required type="text" ui-money-mask="0" >  </input>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container md-no-float >
   <span>This is second field</span>
   <input name="field2" ng-model="field2"  required type="text" ui-money-mask="0"></input>
  </md-input-container>
 </md-content>
</form>
```

Those fields are text fields, but using money-mask, user can insert only number.
Now I have to set max value in field 2. Max value is the value of field1.
I have something like this in the second field:

```
<md-input-container md-no-float >
    <span>This is second field</span>
    <input name="field2" ng-model="field2" required type="text" ui-money-mask="0" max="{{field1}}"></input>
    <div ng-messages="myForm.field2.$error">
      <div ng-message="max">Field2 cannot be greater than field1</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>
```

This doesn't work.
But if i set "max manually (`max="100"`) it works.

Anyone have an idea how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In second field:

```
<input name="field2" ng-model="field2" required type="text" ui-money-mask="0" max="field1"></input>
```